# Python String Format Explanation

Tags: python, string-formatting

I saw this in a code,

```
print('Job: {!r}, {!s}'.format(5,3))
```

and the answer is

```
Job: 5, 3
```

how does `{!r}` evaluate? Does it have any special meaning there?

Comment: What is so terrible about this question to deserve downvoting? For integers `!r` makes no difference from `!s` here, so that can be surprising.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for this comment, some people prefer to down vote before they even read it yet they can't give the solution.

Comment: Your post *does* lack information as to what you expected instead. I had to *infer* from the fact that you also have `{!s}` in your format that you perhaps were surprised there was no difference in output. It would have been helpful had you made it explicit *why* you asked the question, or showed that you had read the documentation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters noted. I would do as you've instructed next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`!r` calls [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) on the value before interpolating.

For integers, the `str()`, default `format()` and `repr()` output doesn't differ. For other types, such as strings, the difference is more visible:

```
>>> print('Repr of a string: {!r}'.format("She said: 'Hello, world!'"))
Repr of a string: "She said: 'Hello, world!'"
```

Note that quotes were included.

See the [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax); the character after `!` specifies the *conversion* applied to the value. The default is no conversion, but you can use either `!r` or `!s` to convert a value to its `repr()` representation or `str()` string output, respectively.

You'd usually use conversion when either dealing with a type that doesn't specify an explicit `__format__()` method (such as `bytes`), when explicitly formatting to the `repr()` output (very helpful for debug output), or when you have to handle a mix of types.

Comment: Martijn  ,is !s for str()??

Comment: @RAJ: yes, I state so in the answer.

Comment: @MartijnThanks, it really helpful answer, it should be get always upwordvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you have the insights of a master. Thanks for the clarity. I wish I could reach you formally through mail, is it possible?

Comment: @iamshola: I reserve email for business and personal contacts only, sorry.

Comment: OK @MartijnPieters. Thanks for the efforts.